# Packaging a Jython Library

Tags: python, jython, packaging

I have a Python library I've written that interfaces with a Java application.  Note that this is specifically a library for other developers to use, there is no `main()` involved.  I've found plenty of information on packaging Jython web applications into jars to be deployed on application servers, but I can't seem to find anything on packaging a library to be installed for others to use.

This is a pretty simple scenario of a single package with 4 modules.  Effectively what I'm looking for is the standard CPython methodology of having a `setup.py` using distutils and running:

```
python setup.py sdist
```

How can I accomplish the same via Jython?

If it matters:

```
jython --version                
Jython 2.2.1 on java1.6.0_20
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation of disutils in jython but it doesn't work for me.  For now you might have to write a script to copy your python files into jython/Lib/site-packages, which I don't think will be too hard if you're just installing python source, see shutil.copytree.

Comment: I just discovered something, my setup.py scripts didn't work when I tried "java -jar C:\jython\jython.jar setup.py <command>" but "C:\jython\jython setup.py <command>" works beautifully.  So just do in jython what you would in python.  I just installed PyPNG and it worked beautifully.

Comment: What version of Jython are you using?

Answer (score 0):

it's strongly recommend to use virtualenv so you can get most up-to-date setuptools and other utils by pip.

I also suggest you to take a look at [jip](https://github.com/sunng87/jip), which will help you to define java dependencies in setup.py. The dependencies will be resolved automatically when user install your module with:

```
pip install ...
```

or

```
jython setup.py install
```

Please upgrade to jython 2.5.x to run it.